Error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0. Either target
I created simple ASP.NET Core project with default templates in Visual Studio 2022 using .NET 8.0 framework and pushed in to Azure repo (included the file .gitignore for Visual Studio) and created a CLASSIC BUILD EDITOR pipeline.
I removed the test cases because my aim is to create an artifact. I am getting an error while the Nuget restore runs. Please refer to the screenshots of this error and what I have done below:







Does this answer your question? NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.1

Hi @Aswinkumar, Have you got a chance to check my answer below where I reproduced your error and fixed the issue by using latest version of Nuget on windows-2022 agent? Hope the information helps and cheers.

I can reproduce the issue based on your description. This is because the template is using the agent of windows-2019 with the default installation of VS2019 & Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7 and the NuGet tool version to be installed is 4.4.1
We can check Always download the latest matching version of the Use NuGet task and opt to use windows-2022 agent to run this pipeline and build the solution.

Please check the Software - Microsoft-hosted agents for Azure Pipelines - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn, so that you may select a Microsoft-hosted agent accordingly.
